# My MVC 4 site keeps flaking out with Directory Listing Denied in IIS6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, deployment, iis-6

I have deployed an MVC4 app out to an IIS6 webserver & initially everything was going well. The site worked as expected.

I checked the site again this morning and got Directory Listing Denied. Odd, it was fine last night.

I restarted iis, double checked my settings for isapi.dll. All was fine. I also redeployed the bin directory. The site was back up and running again after all of that.

Two hours later, I am getting reports back in that it is down again. We are getting Directory Listing Denied message again!!

Can anyone shed any light on what might be causing the site to work for a while & then just fail!?

Many thanks

Comment: Try checking IIS error log, maybe there is some error in your web app that couses app failure. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524984(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thankyou - yes indeed I found the problem in the iis log. one process was trying to run some code that was referencing a dll that my deployment had missed.